# How to entity encode delimiter-in-value when concatenating using T/SQL FOR XML trick

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm using the T/SQL FOR XML trick to concatenate a set of values with a delimiter. I'd like to entity encode my delimiter (| in this case) within the values, but then the FOR XML re-encodes the &#124; so I end up with &amp;#124;

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t
create table #t (v varchar(100))
insert #t(v) values ('Foo'),('A|B'),('Bar')

select (
    select '|' + v AS [text()]
    FROM #t
    FOR XML PATH ('')
) + '|' as vConcat

-- Result of above = |Foo|A|B|Bar| -- delimiter in A|B not escaped

select (
    select '|' + replace(v, '|', '&#124;') AS [text()] 
    FROM #t
    FOR XML PATH ('')
) + '|' as vConcat

-- Result of above = |Foo|A&amp;amp;#124;B|Bar| -- delimiter double-escaped
```

Is there a way to get FOR XML to encode additional characters? Or is there a better way of achieving escaped delimiters inside FOR XML?

Using a different delimiter is not the answer I'm looking for.

I know that wrapping the whole expression in a replace to undo the double encoding will work, but it doesn't strike me as very elegant.

```
select replace((
    select '|' + replace(v, '|', '&#124;') AS [text()] 
    FROM #t
    FOR XML PATH ('')
) + '|', '&amp;#124;', '&#124;') as vConcat

-- Result of above = |Foo|A&#124;B|Bar|
```

**Edit**

To make the question clearer, I want to entity encode my delimiter (within original values only) *in addition to* the usual special XML characters.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t
create table #t (v varchar(100))
insert #t(v) values ('F&o'),('A|B'),('Bar'),('A&#124;B')

select (
    select '|' + v AS [text()]
    FROM #t
    FOR XML PATH ('')
) + '|' as vConcat

-- Result of above = |F&amp;o|A|B|Bar|A&amp;#124;B| -- special chars encoded but not delimiter in A|B value

select (
    select '|' + replace(v, '|', '&#124;') AS [text()] 
    FROM #t
    FOR XML PATH ('')
) + '|' as vConcat

-- Result of above = |F&amp;o|A&amp;#124;B|Bar|A&amp;#124;B| -- delimiter in A|B value double-encoded

-- Desired result = |F&amp;o|A&#124;B|Bar|A&amp;#124;B|
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We need sample data and expected output to help you. Just as a general hint: There's no need to do your own `REPLACE`s, `FOR XML` will do all this implicitly. And using `,TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)')` will re-translate all entities implicitly...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value()` on the XML.

```
SELECT (SELECT '|' + replace(v, '|', '&#124;') AS [text()]
               FROM #t
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)') + '|' vconcat;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=282cab022c4083c53cba530a8e6f87da)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sticky bit but the problem with this approach is that it's now not possible to differentiate a value that originally had '&#124;' in it from one which just had '|' in it. I'll update the question again with more examples.